# needing page to pull just one user based on ID for editing but get them all

Tags: reactjs

This is my edit user page and I would like it to pull one user at a time for editing.

When you click the pencil to edit I would like just the one user pulled but instead I get all of them like in the second image.
[image]
[image]

in the code below I map them out but have tried using filter and a reducer but no fix has worked as of yet. would an inline condition be better like the one below but have not figured how to get the right ID from the URL.

```
{Collectors.CollectorID === Collectors.CollectorID && <div><h2>1-30 days past due in Tandem – all credit types</h2> <p>{Collectors.CollectorCode}{Collectors.FinanceCompany}</p></div>}
```

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class UpdateUser extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    collectorList: [],
    CollectorID: props.CollectorID,
    ProgramBucketID: props.ProgramBucketID,
    CollectorOptionsID: props.CollectorOptionsID,
    FinanceCompanyID: props.FinanceCompanyID,
    Active: '',
    LastName: '',
    CollectorCode: '',
    Aging1to15: '',
    Aging31to45: '',
    Aging31to60: '',
    AgingOver60: '',
    ProgramBucketA: '',
    ProgramBucketB: '',
    ProgramBucketC: '',
    ProgramBucketSU: '',
    FinanceCompany: ''
  }
  this.handleActiveChange = this.handleActiveChange.bind(this);
  this.handleAging115Change = this.handleAging115Change.bind(this);
  this.handleAging3145Change = this.handleAging3145Change.bind(this);
  this.handleAging3160Change = this.handleAging3160Change.bind(this);
  this.handleAgingOver60Change = this.handleAgingOver60Change.bind(this);
  this.handleProgramAChange = this.handleProgramAChange.bind(this);
  this.handleProgramBChange = this.handleProgramBChange.bind(this);
  this.handleProgramCChange = this.handleProgramCChange.bind(this);
  this.handleProgramSUChange = this.handleProgramSUChange.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(e) {
  this.getCollectors()
}

handleActiveChange(e) {
  this.setState({ 
    Active: !this.state.Active
  })
}

handleAging115Change() {
  this.setState({ 
    Aging1to15: !this.state.Aging1to15
  })
}

handleAging3145Change() {
  this.setState({ 
    Aging31to45: !this.state.Aging31to45
  })
}

handleAging3160Change() {
  this.setState({ 
    Aging31to60: !this.state.Aging31to60
  })
}

handleAgingOver60Change() {
  this.setState({ 
    AgingOver60: !this.state.AgingOver60
  })
}

handleProgramAChange() {
  this.setState({
    ProgramBucketA: !this.state.ProgramBucketA
  })
}

handleProgramBChange() {
  this.setState({
    ProgramBucketB: !this.state.ProgramBucketB
  })
}

handleProgramCChange() {
  this.setState({
    ProgramBucketC: !this.state.ProgramBucketC
  })
}

handleProgramSUChange() {
  this.setState({
    ProgramBucketSU: !this.state.ProgramBucketSU
  })
}

  getCollectors = () => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getCollectors`)
    .then((result) => result.data)
    .then((result) => {
      this.setState({collectorList: result});
    });
  };

  onUpdateClick = CollectorID => {
    axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/UpdateUser/${CollectorID}`, {
      CollectorID: this.state.CollectorID,
      CollectorOptionsID: this.state.CollectorOptionsID,
      ProgramBucketID: this.state.ProgramBucketID,
      FinanceCompanyID: this.state.FinanceCompanyID,
      Active: this.state.Active,  
      LastName: this.state.LastName,
      CollectorCode: this.state.CollectorCode,
      Aging1to15: this.state.Aging1to15,
      Aging31to45: this.state.Aging31to45,
      Aging31to60: this.state.Aging31to60,
      AgingOver60: this.state.AgingOver60,
      ProgramBucketA: this.state.ProgramBucketA,
      ProgramBucketB: this.state.ProgramBucketB,
      ProgramBucketC: this.state.ProgramBucketC,
      ProgramBucketSU: this.state.ProgramBucketSU,
      FinanceCompany: this.state.FinanceCompany
    });
  };

  render() {
    // console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>Update Collectors</h1>
      <div className="wrapper">
        {this.state.collectorList.map((Collectors) => (
          <form className="updateUserForm" key={Collectors.CollectorID}>
        <div className="updateUserItem">
          <b>{Collectors.FirstName} {Collectors.LastName} | {Collectors.CollectorCode}</b>
          {/*Active or inactive User*/}
            <label>Active Status</label>
            <input
                type='checkbox'
                name="Active"
                value={this.state.Active}
                defaultChecked={Collectors.Active === false ? false : true}
                onChange={this.handleActiveChange}
                />
          {/*Collector Last Name*/}
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="LastName"
              defaultValue={Collectors.LastName}
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                LastName: e.target.value
              })}
            />
          {/*Collector Code First Initial Middle Initial Last Initial*/}
             <label>Collector Code</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="CollectorCode"
              defaultValue={Collectors.CollectorCode}
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                CollectorCode: e.target.value
              })}
            />
            {/*Aging Bucket selection section */}
            <label>Aging Bucket</label>
            <div className='newUserCheckboxContainer'>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>1-15<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='AgingBucketCheckbox'
                value={this.state.Aging1to15} 
                defaultChecked={Collectors.Aging1to15 === false ? false : true}
                onChange={this.handleAging115Change}
              /></label>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>31-45<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='AgingBucketCheckbox'
                value={this.state.Aging31to45} 
                defaultChecked={Collectors.Aging31to45 === false ? false : true}
                onChange={this.handleAging3145Change}
              /></label>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>31-60<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='AgingBucketCheckboxsm'
                value={this.state.Aging31to60} 
                defaultChecked={Collectors.Aging31to60 === false ? false : true}
                onChange={this.handleAging3160Change}
              /></label>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>Over 60<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='AgingBucketCheckboxlg'
                value={this.state.AgingOver60} 
                defaultChecked={Collectors.AgingOver60 === false ? false : true}
                onChange={this.handleAgingOver60Change}
              /></label>
            </div>
            {/*Progam code selection section*/}
            <label>Program Bucket</label>
            <div className='newUserCheckboxContainer'>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>A<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='ProgramBucketChecbox'
                value={this.state.ProgramBucketA} 
                defaultChecked={Collectors.ProgramBucketA === false ? false : true}
                onChange={this.handleProgramAChange}
              /></label>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>B<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='ProgramBucketChecbox'
                value={this.state.ProgramBucketB} 
                defaultChecked={Collectors.ProgramBucketB === false ? false : true}
                onChange={this.handleProgramBChange}
              /></label>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>C<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='ProgramBucketChecbox'
                value={this.state.ProgramBucketC} 
                defaultChecked={Collectors.ProgramBucketC === false ? false : true}
                onChange={this.handleProgramCChange}
              /></label>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>SU<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='ProgramBucketChecbox'
                value={this.state.ProgramBucketSU} 
                defaultChecked={Collectors.ProgramBucketSU === false ? false : true}
                onChange={this.handleProgramSUChange}
              /></label>
            </div>
            {/*Finance Company selection section*/}
            <label>Finance Company</label>
            <div className='newUserCheckboxContainer'>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>
              <input
                type="text" 
                name="FinanceCompany"
                defaultValue={Collectors.FinanceCompany}
                onChange={e => this.setState({
                  FinanceCompany: e.target.value
                })}
              /></label>
            </div>
            <button className="updateUserButton" onClick={() => this.onUpdateClick(Collectors.CollectorID) }>Update User</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        ))}
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UpdateUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through some tests I found the below code works wonderfully if anyone is having this issue.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

  const UpdateUser = () => {
    const { CollectorID } = useParams();
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
      Active: '',
      FirstName: '',
      LastName: '',
      CollectorCode: ''
      });
    const { Active, FirstName, LastName, CollectorCode } = undefined || user;
    
    const onInputChange = e => {
      setUser({ 
        ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      Active: !Active });
    };

useEffect(() => {
  loadUser();
}, []);// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

const loadUser = async () => {
  const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getCollectors/${CollectorID}`);
  setUser(result.data[CollectorID - 1]);
  // console.log(result.data[CollectorID - 1]);
};

const onSubmit = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/UpdateUser/${CollectorID}`, {
        CollectorID: CollectorID,
        Active: Active,  
        LastName: LastName,
        CollectorCode: CollectorCode
    });
  console.log(CollectorID, Active, LastName, CollectorCode)
};

    return (
      <div className="previewWrapper">
        <h1>Update Collector</h1>
        {FirstName} {LastName} | {CollectorCode} - {CollectorID} {console.log(user)}
            <form className="newUserForm" onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className="newUserItem">
          {/*Active or inactive User*/}
            <label>Active</label>
            <input
                type='checkbox'
                defaultValue={Active}
                defaultChecked={Active}
                onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
                />
          {/*Collector Last Name*/}
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              placeholder="Last Name"
              name="LastName"
              defaultValue={LastName}
              onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
            />
          {/*Collector Code First Initial Middle Initial Last Initial*/}
            <label>Collector Code</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="CollectorCode"
              placeholder="Collector Code" 
              defaultValue={CollectorCode}
              onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
            />
            <button className="newUserButton">Update Collector</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default UpdateUser;
```